# Aplico esta función y me retorna un none al final

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe por qué me retorna un none al final del código y cómo solucionarlo sin usar un `return ''` al final del código?

```py
def rompe_barreras(guia, B1, B2, B3):
    contadorB1=0
    contadorB2=0
    contadorB3=0
    for letra in guia:
        if letra in B1:
            contadorB1+=1
        if letra in B2:
            contadorB2+=1
        if letra in B3:
            contadorB3+=1
    if contadorB1 == len(guia):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
    if contadorB2 == len(guia):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
    if contadorB3 == len(guia):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
guia =str(input())
B1 =str(input()) 
B2 =str(input()) 
B3 =str(input())
print(rompe_barreras(guia, B1, B2, B3))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print(rompe_barreras(guia, B1, B2, B3))
```

En Python todos las funciones tienen, quieras o no, un `return` implícito. Si no lo especificas, devuelve `None`. En esa línea, `print()` está esperando algo para imprimir y la función, al no tener `return` explícito, retorna `None` y este aparece en pantalla. Todo está trabajando a la perfección :).

Si solo quieres ejecutar esa función, pues, elimina el `print()`

```
rompe_barreras(guia, B1, B2, B3)
```